# Получение внутреннего алиаса контейнера независимо от его шаблонных параметров

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, stl

Ситуация следующего характера:

В проекте активно используется ряд STL контейнеров, для примера оставим только std::vector и std::map. Каждый из них имеет в себе метод "at". Его проблема заключается в том, что при отсутствии необходимого ключа/индекса в контейнере он выбрасывает неинформативное исключение (В частности для std::map - "invalid map<K, T> key"). Хотелось бы получить больше информации из такой ситуации, в результате чего мною была написана вот такая функция:

```
template <typename CntT, typename KeyT>
auto at(const CntT& container, const KeyT& key) -> decltype(container.at(key))
{
    using CKeyType = decltype(detail::GetKeyObject(container));

    const auto safeKey    = static_cast<CKeyType>(key); // Необходимо для случая, когда ключ в мапе например uint16_t, а в нее передают enum, образованный от int. В реальности там немного другой каст, который осуществляет все нужные проверки по потере данных
    const bool valueExist = detail::IsExists(container, safeKey);

    if (!valueExist)
    {
        // Генерация кастомного исключения
    }

    return container.at(safeKey);
}
```

Так как тип ключа/индекса в std::map и в std::vector называются по разному (соответственно key_type для map и size_type для vector), и проверка существования ключа также проходит по разному для этих контейнеров, то были реализованы следующие шаблонные функции с их специализациями:

Для проверки существования:

```
template <typename CntT, typename KeyT>
bool IsExists(const CntT& container, const KeyT& key)
{
    return IsExistsImpl(container, key);
}

template <typename KeyT,
          typename ValT,
          typename PredT,
          typename AllocT>
bool IsExistsImpl(const std::map<KeyT, ValT, PredT, AllocT>&   map,
                  const KeyT&                                  key)
{
    return map.find(key) != map.end();
}

template <typename ValT,
          typename AllocT>
bool IsExistsImpl(const std::vector<ValT, AllocT>&              vec,
                  const typename std::vector<ValT>::size_type&  key)
{
    return key < vec.size();
}
```

Для получения типа хранимого класса:

```
template <typename CntT>
auto GetKeyObject(const CntT& container)
{
    return GetKeyObjectImpl(container);
}

template <typename KeyT,
          typename ValT,
          typename PredT,
          typename AllocT>
auto GetKeyObjectImpl(const std::map<KeyT, ValT, PredT, AllocT>&)
{
    return std::declval<typename std::map<KeyT, ValT, PredT, AllocT>::key_type>();
}

template <typename ValT,
          typename AllocT>
auto GetKeyObjectImpl(const std::vector<ValT, AllocT>&)
{
    return std::declval<typename std::vector<ValT>::size_type>();
}
```

Данные код работает хорошо, однако очень смущает способ получения нужного типа, хочется сделать покрасивее, например по аналогии с type_traits. Всвязи с чем попытался написать аналогичные конструкции:

```
template <typename CntT>
struct ContainerTraits;

template <typename KeyT,
          typename ValT,
          typename PredT,
          typename AllocT>
struct ContainerTraits<std::map<KeyT, ValT, PredT, AllocT>>
{
    using KeyType = typename std::map<KeyT, ValT, PredT, AllocT>::key_type;
    using ValType = typename std::map<KeyT, ValT, PredT, AllocT>::mapped_type;
};

template <typename ValT,
          typename AllocT>
struct ContainerTraits<std::vector<ValT, AllocT>>
{
    using KeyType = typename std::vector<ValT, AllocT>::size_type;
    using ValType = typename std::vector<ValT, AllocT>::value_type;
};
```

Однако, при попытке использования нового варианта получаю следующие ошибки:

```
error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<'
error C2059: syntax error: '<'
error C2065: 'ValT': undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'AllocT': undeclared identifier
error C2923: 'std::vector': 'ValT' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'
error C2923: 'std::vector': 'AllocT' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Alloc'
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
error C2976: 'detail::ContainerTraits': too few template arguments
note: see declaration of 'detail::ContainerTraits'
error C2976: 'detail::ContainerTraits': too few template arguments
note: see declaration of 'detail::ContainerTraits'
error C2977: 'detail::ContainerTraits': too many template arguments
note: see declaration of 'detail::ContainerTraits'
error C2977: 'detail::ContainerTraits': too many template arguments
note: see declaration of 'detail::ContainerTraits'
error C2976: 'detail::ContainerTraits': too few template arguments
note: see declaration of 'detail::ContainerTraits'
```

Сами ошибки мне в принципе понятны. Непонятно - как правильно сделать то, что мне нужно, а именно, заставить резолвиться тип индекса/ключа для конкретного контейнера, независимо от того, какие шаблонные параметры были ему переданы (может прийти мапа как со стандартным аллокатором, так и с кастомным и т.д.). В шаблонах не очень силен, так что если пытаюсь изобрести велосипед - с радостью заиспользую готовое решение.
Ограничен следующим стеком:

С++11

boost 1.51

Comment: Приведите [mre], чтобы получить эти ошибки

Comment: У меня все работает... https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1WzcxT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variadic Templates решили проблему.

```
template <typename... Args>
struct ContainerTraits;

template <typename... Args>
struct ContainerTraits<std::vector<Args...>>
{
    using KeyType = typename std::vector<Args...>::size_type;
    using ValType = typename std::vector<Args...>::value_type;
};

template <typename... Args>
struct ContainerTraits<std::map<Args...>>
{
    using KeyType = typename std::map<Args...>::key_type;
    using ValType = typename std::map<Args...>::mapped_type;
};
```

Соответственно сама функция at теперь выглядит следующим образом:

```
template <typename CntT, typename KeyT>
auto at(const CntT& container, const KeyT& key) -> decltype(container.at(key))
{
    using CKeyType = typename detail::ContainerTraits<CntT>::KeyType;

    const auto safeKey    = static_cast<CKeyType>(key);
    const bool valueExist = detail::IsExists(container, safeKey);

    if (!valueExist)
    {
        // Генерация кастомного исключения
    }

    return container.at(safeKey);
}
```